# Verilog input and binary output

Tags: verilog

I am trying to take 4 inputs from physical switches and based on their state send out on 2 pins I have turned on on my CPLD a 1 or a 0.  I am totaly lost on how to do this..........This is what I have so far.  Any ideas?

```
module count_osc (rstn, osc_clk, clk, LED, but1, but2, but3, but4, STM);

input   rstn;
input   but1, but2, but3, but4;
output  osc_clk;
output  clk;  
output  [2:0] STM;
output  [7:0] LED;

GSR GSR_INST (.GSR(rstn));          
OSCC OSCC_1 (.OSC(osc_clk));

reg [3:0] switches;             
reg [7:0] LED;
reg [2:0] STM;

always @(but1 || but2 || but3 || but4) begin
    if(but2 && but4 && !but1 && !but3)
         STM = 4'b0000;
    else if(but2 && but3 && !but1 && !but4)
         STM = 4'b0001;
    else if(but1 && but3 && !but2 && !but4)
         STM = 4'b0010;
    else if(but1 && but2 && but3 && !but4)
         STM = 4'b0011  
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: I tried to build a case that switched based on my switch state, but that failed as well.  A case seems more suitable to me, however being a very weak programmer, I can't wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify

```
always @(but1 || but2 || but3 || but4) begin
```

to

```
always @(but1, but2, but3, but4) begin
```

and it will work :-)

`always @(but1 || but2 || but3 || but4)` doesn't mean *"when any of but1 .. but4 changes"* but rather *"when the signal obtained by logically ORing but1 .. but4 changes"*

Another issue in the if..else ladder: You need to specify an `else` condition. Without an explicit else, the simulator wouldn't know what to drive STM when none of the conditions mentioned in the if..elseif cases are present; and in such cases, it will typically try to retain the previous value of STM. This may not be what you expect your code to do. Another problem is that since STM does not have any value assigned at the start of the simulation and you might end up seeing X on it for a very long time..

Answer (score 2):

TO add to @navs' answer I would replace manual sensitivity lists with automatic once to reduce your chance of RTL to Gates (synthesis) mismatch.

```
always @(but1, but2, but3, but4) begin
```

Becomes :

```
always @* begin
```

Looking at your conditionals, It would be much easier to understand if you kept the arguments in the same order:

```
if(but2 && but4 && !but1 && !but3)
     STM = 4'b0000;
else if(but2 && but3 && !but1 && !but4)
     STM = 4'b0001;
else if(but1 && but3 && !but2 && !but4)
     STM = 4'b0010;
else if(but1 && but2 && but3 && !but4)
     STM = 4'b0011  
end
```

becomes :

```
if( !but1 && but2 && !but3 && but4 )
     STM = 4'b0000;
else if(!but1 && but2 && but3 &&  !but4)
     STM = 4'b0001;
else if(but1 && !but2 && but3 && !but4)
     STM = 4'b0010;
else if(but1 && but2 && but3 && !but4)
     STM = 4'b0011  
end
```

This now becomes easier to turn into a case statement:

```
case( {but1,but2,but3,but4} )
   4'b0101 : STM = 4'b0000;
   4'b0110 : STM = 4'b0001;
   4'b1010 : STM = 4'b0010;
   4'b1110 : STM = 4'b0011;
endcase
```

Note that you do not define all the output for all states therefore you will be implying a latch. Accidentally implying a latch is considered bad practise and can lead to hard to track timing issues. As well as RTL to Gate level mismatch. I would recommend adding a default case which does something sensible.

```
always @* begin
  case( {but1,but2,but3,but4} )
     4'b0101 : STM = 4'b0000;
     4'b0110 : STM = 4'b0001;
     4'b1010 : STM = 4'b0010;
     4'b1110 : STM = 4'b0011;
     default : STM = 4'b0000;
  endcase
end
```

Note2: you probably want to do some clean up of the button presses, de-bouncing or at a minimum putting through meta stability flip-flops. It is likely that you want to add edge detection circuit so that you only get a 1 clock cycle wide pulse per press.